# Paypal- Mass Pay Implementation

Tags: php, paypal, masspay

Have been searching for mass pay help but found nothing..!! have read Paypal guide to     send credentials and user information to pay but not able to find what format of data it will accept ?? new to Php and paypal ??

Answer (score 1):

PayPal just made a REST version of Payouts available.

Here s the Payouts Overview:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/

To get access:
Go to your dashboard on developer.paypal.com
Go to My account
Click Get Started under Payouts
When you make it through you'll also have Mass Payments capability

Answer (score 0):

It'll handle [NVP](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/) or [SOAP](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_SOAP/).

Since you're working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [PayPal PHP Library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It will make this very simple for you.  Specifically, the [MassPay.php](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/templates/MassPay.php) template.  There is also a [sample](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/samples/MassPay.php) already filled out and [functioning here](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/MassPay.php).  You could have this done in a matter of minutes.  :)